# Reading xml file and printing using python

Tags: python

First : am a new beg. using python..so please help me out.I'm trying to read a XML file using Python. My xml file name is rgpost.xml

```
<volume name="sp" type="span" operation="create">
    <driver>HDD1</driver>
</volume>
```

My code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.parse("rgpost.xml")
s = doc.find("volume")
print s.attrib["name"]
```

While running this am getting error :

```
sp:~# python volume_check.py volume  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "volume_check.py", line 13, in <module>  
    print s.attrib["name"]  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never run your script as root unless you _really_ have to.

Comment: i change root.but still not workingg

Comment: This was rather a recommendation than a fix for your problem. It's a good practice, imagine your script has a severe bug that causes data loss and has root access...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Life is much easier if you get the root:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> doc = ET.parse("rgpost.xml")
>>> root = doc.getroot() # <--- this is the new line
>>> root
<Element 'volume' at 0x1004d8f10>
>>> root.keys()
['operation', 'type', 'name']
>>> root.attrib["name"]
'sp'
>>> root.get("name")
'sp'
```

Comment: Great baba great...super :) its working. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

`volume` is considered the root of the XML tree, so what you want is effectively `doc.attrib['name']`.

```
xml="""<volume name="sp" type="span" operation="create">
    <driver>HDD1</driver>
</volume>"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.fromstring(xml)
print doc
# <Element 'volume' at 0x26f1d50>
print doc.attrib['name']
```

Comment: not working still :( AttributeError: ElementTree instance has no attribute 'attrib'